# Парадигма склонения местоимения "ТУТ"

Tags: склонение, местоимение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно просклонять указательное местоимение "тут"? Преподаватель утверждает, что это возможно.

Answer (score 5):

Или ваш преподаватель - большой оригинал, или вы что-то не так поняли.
*Тут* - наречие, по падежам, естественно, не изменяется. Ни в одном словаре не нашел иного.

Могу предположить несколько вариантов возникновения ошибки.

1. Вы спутали с "т**о**т" (это действительно указательное местоимение).
2. Речь идет о существительном *тут* (=тутовник).
3. Вы (или кто-то) ошибочно причислили *"тут"* к указательным местоимением - на что и получили от преподавателя ответ: "Ну тогда просклоняйте его".

Но гадать не хочу, переспросите преподавателя.

На всякий случай. Третий пункт в моем "списке вариантов" обусловлен тем, что все указательные местоимения склоняются ([см.](http://megabook.ru/article/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

По своему смыслу и грамматической роли местоимения заменяют в предложениях имена (существительные, прилагательные/причастия, числительные). "Тут" тоже в каком-то смысле является неким указательным словом, и отчасти даже может заменять отдельные имена, **но только в наречном значении - места или времени** - и, как правило, с предлогами (в ящике, на столе, под кроватью; тот час же, в [эту] секунду).  Таким образом, *тут* - **указательное наречие** (места или времени).

Посмотрел. В некоторых случаях "тут" причисляют к частицам. ("Тут ко мне пришли, позже позвоню"), но от того склоняемой частью речи, оно, понятно, не становится. Других вариантов нет.

Answer (score 0):

> Указательные  местоимения: здесь, там, тут, дотуда, досюда, отсюда,
>   оттуда, сюда, туда

*[Энциклопедия русского языка](http://russkiyyazik.ru/949/), ст. "Указательные местоимения"*

Наречие **тут** [признаётся местоимением](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и лингвистами-авторами сайта rusgram.ru c примечанием:

> В [Грамматика 1980] к местоимениям отнесены только местоименные
>   существительные и прилагательные. А местоименные наречия типа здесь,
>   сюда не считаются местоимениями. Мы не придерживаемся этого
>   ограничения, см. статью [Местоимение](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#sm_p).
>
> > Указательные местоимения выделяют фиксированный элемент некоторого множества [Левин 1973]. В этот семантический класс входят единицы разных морфосинтаксических классов:
> >
> > местоимения-существительные этот, тот;
> >     прилагательные такой, таковой, таков, экий, экой, этакий, эдакий, сей, оный;
> >     наречия здесь, там, тут, туда, оттуда, потому, поэтому, затем, оттого, тогда. так, этак, эдак, настолько.

[image]

Что касается склонения, то в рамках нормативной лексики русского языка я могу просклонять его только в местном ([ал]лативном) и отделительном (аблативном) падежах - **сюда** и **отсюда**, не смотря на то, что этимологически это разные слова.
В диалектах оно может склоняться и в творительном - **сюдой** или **сюдом** (*ср.* дом - дОма, домой).

Answer (score 0):

До реформы Пётра слова тут не существовало, также как и слов тот. В них место использовалось ту и тои.

Comment: Есть нечто вроде справки, но нет ответа.